# Creating a temperature program using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, output

I am writing a small Python/Tkinter program for yearly temperatures.

I can get nearly everything working as a textual program, but I'm wanting to implement it into a GUI.

The program opens a `csv` file, reads it into lists, works out the average, and min & max temps. Then, on closing, the application will save a summary to a new text file.

I am wanting the default start up screen to show all Years. When a Button is clicked it just shows that year's data.

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Pretty simple layout, with just the 5 Buttons and the out puts for each.

I can make up the Buttons for the top with:

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="All Years", command=self.All)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2011", command=self.Y1)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2012", command=self.Y2)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2013", command=self.Y3)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Save & Exit", command=self.Exit)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
```

I'm not sure how to do the other elements, such as the title and the table.

Once I have the structure/framework I think I can populate the fields, and I might learn better this way.

Comment: Basically you need to make a `Text` widget and call its `insert` method to add text strings to it. I suggest you find a `tkinter` tutorial or a book on using it. To get you started here's a [reference guide](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/) and something else titled [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Here's another good resource I just found called the [Tkinter Wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/FrontPage).

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite resource for Tkinter: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

The title can be a label: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm

```
w = Label(master, text="Hello, world!")
w.grid(column=1,row=1)
```

For everything else, create an entry widget for:

```
textBox = Text(self, height=1,width=1)
textBox.grid(sticky=E,column=1,row=1)
```

Then insert the data like so:

```
self.textBox.insert('end',yourText)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back so fast. I have been reading over the links posted and to tell the truth I think im getting even more lost ><. Would it be possible to post the code to make say 2 buttons and then when u click one below it says  total statically then next to it the answer that changes with each button press. it think if i had that layout i should be able to go from there.

Comment: Check out jbaldwins answer below. It looks correct. Make sure to note that commands for buttons do not include "()". Without the parenthesis, they become functions associated with the buttons without actually executing the functions.

Comment: Seems I should of used grid. might of saved me hassles. Im slowly getting there but im still having probles. below is my code. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, I recommend using ttk.Treeview for making the table, it's a really useful tool, although it might seen difficult to work

here is a small example to help you see what I mean

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="All Years", command=self.All)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2011", command=self.Y1)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2012", command=self.Y2)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2013", command=self.Y3)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Save & Exit", command=self.Exit)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        frame2 = Frame(master)
        frame2.pack()
        treedata = [('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2')]
        column_names = ("heading1", "heading2")
        tree = ttk.Treeview(frame2, columns = column_names)

        for x in treedata:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values =x)
        for col in column_names: 
            tree.heading(col, text = col.Title())
        tree.pack()
```

hope this helps there isn't a lot of docs on this, but google will help, one very helpful link: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

good luck :)

if you need any more help just ask in a comment :)

Comment: obviously just add a Label from tk for the Title, forgot about that :P

Comment: Hey thanks. I have tried this and got a lil lost >< I have posted my code as to where im at below.

Answer (score 0):

An option you may want to consider is instead of using tkinter's `.pack()` function, use the `.grid()` function. This allows you to much more dynamically arrange your objects into the way you want it, and works great for what you're doing (creating a grid).

Once you do that, you can take the csv file information and save the text as a variable (let's say `csvText`). Then, print the variable as a label using:

```
dataText = Tkinter.Label(root,text=csvText)
dataText.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

and do that for each piece of information. The title at the top would be packed into the grid the same way, except using the `columnspan` attribute:

```
title = Tkinter.Label(root,text="TITLE")
title.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=4)
```

Your buttons would be the same, except instead of using `.pack(side=LEFT)`, you would pack them by doing:

```
self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="All Years", command=self.All)
self.hi_there.grid(row=0,column=0)

self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2011", command=self.Y1)
self.hi_there.grid(row=0,column=1)

self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2012", command=self.Y2)
self.hi_there.grid(row=0,column=2)

self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="2013", command=self.Y3)
self.hi_there.grid(row=0,column=3)

self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Save & Exit", command=self.Exit)
self.hi_there.grid(row=0,column=4)
```

All the button functions would then have to be is finding the new csv information, storing them in the same `csvText` variables, and passing those on to an update function that updates the labels. Note that when you redraw something to the screen, It won't wipe everything and start from scratch, so when redrawing, don't redraw all of the buttons and the title, just redraw all of your labels. That will save you lines of code and make it slightly more optimized.

Comment: been trying to get this implemented in my code and haveing a few troubles. I have just posted where im at below - the code etc. your advice is great and think that the way i should of gone ><

Comment: @LewisTownsend: are you aware that answers can appear in somewhat random order? For instance, at the time that I write this comment, this answer is the last one on the screen. So, when you say "below", it makes no sense.